# Using Amazon EC2 with Hover.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ec2

I have a domain name registered with Hover.com and I'd like to use it to point to an Amazon EC2 Instance. I can't seem to figure out the proper way to do this, despite my Google-fu. If anyone has had some experience with using these two services together, some advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to do this, the simplest is pointing the domains A record to an IP address that is associated with an instance. So:

1. Go to EC2 dashboard
2. Create an Elastic IP
3. Point the A record to this Elastic IP
4. Associate the Elastic IP to an instance.

This link http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346 should help although it is using the command line tools. The steps above are for the GUI.

The other method is to use Route 53 - this guide helped me out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/R53Example.html